# What is the best automatic chess playing app for a beginning level player?

Tags: engines, learning

I play chess very infrequently. Whenever I restart, I take a bit of time to get up to speed. Which chess playing apps are best for a beginner? I would prefer apps that scale up in diifficulty according to a player's skill.

Comment: either I miserably humiliate the AI, or it humiliates me... I stopped trying to find a balanced AI years ago, now I play online chess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the day, I found Chessmaster to be very beginner friendly, with a variety of AIs to choose from. It also had some instructional segments included, which were good at the time.

Now I lose against Stockfish whenever I'm looking for a good beating. I don't think it's very good for beginners, even if you constrain its skill quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Shredder is an awesome Chess Program.  If you have an IPhone or Android Shredder is present and if you want for Computer along with Shredder you can use Fritz also.  I personally like both of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Microsoft Windows-based PC or laptop then there is no problem. They provide a very good chess game with different skill levels and appearances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess one needs to choose that at the time of install. My current installation doesn't appear to have it. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to improve your skills, maybe [gamezer.com](http://gamezer.com/) is useful. It's not an app, but a website you can visit with an iphone, ipod, or whatever smartphone. It also provides skill  levels.